# raster tiles from vector data with GDAL - how to avoid aliasing artefacts?

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles

## Prequesites

I have vector data in a Shapefile `N47E007_CONTOURS.shp` produced with

```sh
wget -O N47E007.zip http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/SRTM/SRTMGL1.003/2000.02.11/N47E007.SRTMGL1.hgt.zip
unzip N47E007.zip

# Convert from WGS 84 to Web Mercator and from HGT to GeoTIFF
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 N47E007.hgt \
         -t_srs EPSG:3785 N47E007_WebMercator.tif \
         -co "COMPRESS=LZW" -of GTiff -r bilinear

# Compute contour vector data
gdal_contour -a elev -i 20 N47E007_WebMercator.tif N47E007_CONTOURS.shp
```

(Contour lines based on one patch (`N47E007`) of NASA SRTM elevation data.)

## Process

From this, I generate TMS/WMTS tiles to be used by leaflet, by first rasterizing the vector data from the Shapefile with `gdal_rasterize` and then tiling it with `gdal2tiles.py`. I repeat both steps for every zoomlevel, so I can rasterize to a larger raster for higher zoomlevels, so that lines will have the same on-screen thickness on each one:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for z in $(seq 1 15)
do
    gdal_rasterize \
        --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 1024 \
        -ts $(calc "2851 << (${z} - 12)") \
            $(calc "4220 << (${z} - 12)") \
        -ot byte -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE -co PREDICTOR=2 -co ZLEVEL=9 \
        -ot Byte -burn 0 -a_nodata 255 \
        -l N47E007_CONTOURS N47E007_CONTOURS.shp N47E007_CONTOURS_rasterized_z${z}.tif
    gdal2tiles.py \
        -r near -z${z} -a 255,255,255 \
        -e N47E007_CONTOURS_rasterized_z${z}.tif \
        N47E007_contours_tiled
done
```

### Adapting resolution to zoomelevel

(See also [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144920/problem-with-contour-lines-thickness-in-bigger-zoom-levels/146248#146248) to [Problem with contour lines thickness in bigger zoom levels](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144920).)

`calc "2851 << (${z} - 12)"` and `calc "4220 << (${z} - 12)"` compute the size of the image to rasterize to (`N47E007_CONTOURS_rasterized_z${z}.tif`) depending on the zoomelevel `$z`.

`<<` is the binary left-shift operator, so this translates to 2851⋅2 <sup>z-12</sup> and 4220⋅2 <sup>z-12</sup>. This means that

- for zoomlevel 12, the intermediate raster image
  `N47E007_CONTOURS_rasterized_z12.tif` will be 2851×4220 pixels,
- for zoom level 13 (`N47E007_CONTOURS_rasterized_z13.tif`) it will be
  twice that in each direction (5702×8440) and
- for zoom level 11 (`N47E007_CONTOURS_rasterized_z11.tif`) half that
  of zoomlevel 12, i.e. 1425×2110.

#### Imprecise parametrization

The numbers `2851` and `4220` (the size for zoomelevel 12) were guessed or measured on screen or otherwise derived in an imprecise manner.

## Problem

The resulting tiles show some artefacts that aren't visible in the intermediate (untiled) rasterized images:

- double-width segments of lines,
   e.g. `13/4270/5331.png` vs. corresponding excerpt of `N47E007_CONTOURS_rasterized_z13.tif`

  [image: 13/4270/5331.png - example for double-width segments of lines] vs. [image: excerpt of N47E007_CONTOURS_rasterized_z13.tif - all lines 1px thick]
- gaps in lines,
   e.g. at tile edges between

  `14/8536/10665.png` `14/8537/10665.png`
  `14/8536/10664.png` `14/8537/10664.png`

  [image: 14/8536/10665.png - top left of example for gaps in lines][image: 14/8537/10665.png - top right of example for gaps in lines]
  [image: 14/8536/10664.png - bottom left of example for gaps in lines][image: 14/8537/10664.png - bottom right of example for gaps in lines]

  corresponding excerpt from `N47E007_CONTOURS_rasterized_z14.tif` for comparison: [image: excerpt from N47E007_CONTOURS_rasterized_z14.tif - no gaps]

If I skip `-r near` (so rasterization uses the default resampling mode '`average`') I instead get some washed-out pixels which make the lines look unsharp.

### My theory

The coordinate reference systems already match (due to the `gdalwarp` step before calculating the contours), so no general transformation/re-projection should be required. But because the size to rasterize to only approximates the on-screen size of the geographic area covered by the `N47E007` data patch, some rescaling must still happen in `gdal2tiles.py`, to produce correctly placed and sized seamless tiles.

With `-r near` this causes some kind of macroscopic Moiré effect, because the pixel grids of the tiles and of the intermediate raster only almost match. (Additionally, `gdal2tiles.py` might not look accross tile boarders when looking for the nearest pixel in the source image, causing the gaps.) With `average` (the default for `-r`), the same causes effect the washed-out look because values from more than one source pixel get 'mixed' to get the value for a given tile pixel.

Thus, if I knew the correct (zoom-level-dependant) on-screen-size of the geographic area of the data patch and would use that for rasterization, the artifacts should go away.

## Questions

- Is my theory correct?
- If so, how can I determine the precise `-ts` parameters for `gdal_rasterize` (or, alternatively, `-tr` parameters) so that no rescaling (or a reschaling without effect) will be done by `gdal2tiles.py`?

Comment: Does it have to be scriptable? Otherwise give the QGIS plugin QTiles a try, it would do the vector -> raster conversion for you and hopefully does so perfectly. It runs gdal in the background.

If that is not an option, maybe you can specify the scale instead? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

Comment: Yes, I need this in a command that I call from another program, so it needs to be 'scriptable'. Thus QGIS is not an option. But I was interested whether this can be done purely with what GDAL provides. I have a solution now, which I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is my theory correct?

It seems so, as I get flawless results with the method described below.

> If so, how can I determine the precise `-ts` parameters for `gdal_rasterize` (or, alternatively, `-tr` parameters) so that no rescaling (or a reschaling without effect) will be done by `gdal2tiles.py`?

While `gdal2tiles.py` is meant to be used as a command, we can load it as a python module and use the very same functions it uses itself for the size computations. Thus, I've made me this little python script:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from gdal2tiles import GlobalMercator

def main():
    lat, lon = [ float(arg) for arg in sys.argv[1:3] ]
    zoom = int(sys.argv[3])
    px, py = lat_lon_to_pixels(lat, lon, zoom)
    print(px, py)

def lat_lon_to_pixels(lat, lon, zoom):
    gm = GlobalMercator()
    mx, my = gm.LatLonToMeters(lat, lon)
    return tuple( int(round(p)) for p in gm.MetersToPixels(mx, my, zoom) )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I then use the WGS 84 coordinates from `gdalinfo N47E007.hgt` (exctracting them with the regular expressions `/^\s*Upper Right\s*\(\s*(?<east>\d+\.?\d*),\s*(?<north>\d+\.?\d*)\)` and `/^\s*Lower Left\s*\(\s*(?<west>\d+\.?\d*),\s*(?<south>\d+\.?\d*)\)/`) to call `lat_lon_to_pixels` from the python script above for the north-east corner and the south-west corner and compute the differences, which I then use as argument for the `-ts` option of `gdal_rasterize`. (This only works because this HGT file has WGS 84 as coordinate reference system and WGS 84 and WebMercator are axis-aligned to each other.)